# Alphabetical index with millions of rows in redis

Tags: indexing, redis

For my application, I need an alphabetical index on a set with millions of rows.
When I use a sorted set, and give all members the same score, the result looks perfect.
Performance is also great, with a test set of 2 million rows, the last third does not perform noticably less than the first third of the set.

However, I need to query those results. For example, get the first (max) 100 items that start with "goo". I played around with zscan and sort, but it does not give me a working and performant result.

Since redis is very fast when inserting a new member to the sorted set, it must be technically possible to immediately (well, very quickly) go to the right memory location. I suppose redis uses some kind of quicksort mechanism to accomplish this.
But.. I don't seem to get the result when I just want to query the data, and not write to it.

We use replicated slaves for read actions, and we prefer the (default) read-only config switch. So creating a dummy key and deleting it afterward (however unelegant) is not really an option.

I'm stuck a bit, and I'm thinking about writing a ZLEX command in redis-server itself. Which I could use like this:

```lua
HELP "ZLEX" -> (ZLEX set score startswith) 
-- Query the lexicographical index of a sorted set, supplying a 'startswith' string.

127.0.0.1:12345> ZLEX myset 0 goo LIMIT 0 100

1) goo
2) goof
3) goons
4) goozer
```

What are your thoughts? Am I missing something in the standard redis commands?

We're using Redis 2.8.4 x64 on Debian.

Kind regards, TW

***Edits:***

Note:
[Related issue: indexing-using-redis-sorted-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431719/indexing-using-redis-sorted-sets) -> At least the name I gave to ZLEX seems to conform with Antirez' (Salvatore's) standards. As of 24-1-2014, I'm working on implementing ZLEX. It seems to be the easiest and most straight-forward solution for this use case, and Antirez could merge it into the main branch for everyone's benefit.

Comment: Update: Tested ZLEX on a custom build of 2.8.7, works very fast. Test set of 2 million rows in a ZSET with identical scores: All lookups below 1ms. It seems this was the right approach. I'll share it when I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented `ZLEX`.

Here are the full [specs](https://github.com/tw-bert/redis-zlex/wiki/ZLEX-redis-server-extension).
You can grab the new functionality from here: [github tw-bert](https://github.com/tw-bert/redis-zlex/)

I also posted a pull request to Antirez [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/1634).

Kind regards, TW

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at  [this](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html) ?

It can be useful depending on the length of the field by which you sort, this method requires b*(a^2) keys, where a is the length of the field , and b is amount of rows for this field.

Comment: Hi Shachaf, yes, I've read that blog entry by Antirez quite a while back. Thanks for sharing, and it's definitely on the right track. However, it adds a lot of overhead to the index. And that overhead is mainly a trick, and doesn't make things simpler imho. And I like simple... :)

The data we put in redis is replicated from a big RDBMS, and record changes are pushed to redis on CRUD actions in the main database. Since I'd like the index update to be transactional (along with the record which we msgpack-ize), I prefer no more logic than a simple ZADD.  ZLEX = working but needs test btw.